# Adobe Flash cs6 - actionscript

Tags: flash

I am using flash cs6. I have an animation of gift box and I need to type in "dear user.. you have a gift of ** sent by another user". I need to know a script where I can fetch the name of the receiver from an external database and the sender as well. This animation is there where a user logs in his account.

Any help ?

Comment: You have to write a script ( PHP, ASP, ... ) to get the data from your DB and then you can pass it to your swf using [`flashvars'](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/pass-variables-swfs-flashvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you're connecting to a MySQL database you'd normally utilise a php script along the lines of:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

 $sql = 'SELECT persons_name
 FROM table_of_users';

 $q = $conn->query($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
 die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
?>
```

The include at the top would contain your connection details (path,user,pswd)

Comment: @RajeshS did this solve your issue or are you still having problems?